# How to get execution stats for a PL/SQL function?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL function that is called from our Java code.

I have the `SQL_ID` of the PL/SQL function execution and I have access to V$ views on my read-only DB user. The query takes quite some time to execute? Is there a way to profile the PL/SQL function execution to check where exactly the execution is stuck?

I know how to do this for SQL queries with `V$SQL`, `V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY` and `V$SESSION_LONGOPS`, but I am unable to figure out how to do this for PL/SQL code.

The PL/SQL function takes 4 minutes to execute, so I can execute quite a few V$ queries manually in that time. What V$ views should I check to find a line in the execution plan/function? Is this even possible?

Comment: `Is there a way to profile the PL/SQL function..?` Yes. [DBMS_HPROF + plshprof utility](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_profiler.htm)

Comment: You should also consider instrumenting your code - you could log to a table and/or to dbms_application_info - either (both!) would help you to spot where issues are occurring during run time without having to do a profile (although that can be useful too, but typically isn't possible when the issue is occurring in production)

Comment: In addition to DBMS_HPROF, there is the old DBMS_PROFILER which is more basic but doesn't require server file access. (This is built into [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) making it super-convenient if that's the tool you have.)

Comment: Just to clarify the difference between the two: DBMS_HPROF only provides cost at a PL/SQL function level and any embedded SQL statements which is usually sufficient. DBMS_PROFILER on the other hand gives information at line level granularity by is also slower.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use DBMS_PROFILER for your problem. But if you want to use this method, you have to install some infrastructure. 
I don't want to describe the process how to install "proftab.sql", [this link shows how it works.](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbms_profiler.htm)

It also shows some quick examples how to trace a specific function.
I can provide my version of the analyze-query after some testing:

```
select ppr.runid,
   ppr.run_comment1,
   decode(nvl(ppd.total_occur, 0), 0, 0,  ppd.total_time / ppd.total_occur / 1000000) as Avg_msek,
   ppd.total_time / 1000000 totaltime_msek,
   ppd.total_occur,
   uc.name,
   uc.line,
   uc.text as Source
  from plsql_profiler_data ppd, plsql_profiler_units ppu, user_source uc, plsql_profiler_runs ppr
 where ppd.runid = ppu.runid
   and ppu.runid = ppr.runid
--   and ppr.run_comment1 = 'MYTEST' --show only a specific testrun
-- and ppr.runid         = (select max(runid) from plsql_profiler_runs) /*to get the last run*/
   and ppd.unit_number = ppu.unit_number
   and ppu.unit_name = uc.name
   and ppd.line#(+) = uc.line
   and uc.type in ('PACKAGE BODY', 'TYPE BODY')
--order by uc.name, uc.line; --Show all code by line
--order by totaltime_msek desc; --Sort by slowest lines
order by total_occur desc, avg_msek desc --Sort by calls and slowest ones
```